# What are the names of all the books in Quantum Conundrum?

Tags: quantum-conundrum

The book titles in this game are hilarious!  What are they all?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are, in alphabetical order *(along with the book/movie/play they reference)*:

- **ಠ_ಠ Book of Disapproval** *([Internet Meme](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/%E0%B2%A0%E0%B2%A0-look-of-disapproval))*
- **√7 Brides for √-7 brothers** *(7 Brides for 7 Brothers)*
- **A Farewell to Argon** *(A Farewell to Arms)*
- **Around the World in 80 Shifts** *(Around the World in 80 Days)*
- **Atlas Shifted** *(Atlas Shrugged)*
- **Beowatt** *(Beowulf)*
- **Beyond Fluffy and Heavy** *(Beyond Good and Evil)*
- **Ender's Gamma** *(Ender's Game)*
- **Goodnight Muon** *(Goodnight Moon)*
- **Great Exponentiations** *(Great Expectations)*
- **Heart of Dark Matter** *(Heart of Darkness)*
- **Henry^8** *(Henry the 8th)*
- **Hitchhikers Guide to Dimensions** *(Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy)*
- **Ho:ratio Hornblower** *(Horatio Hornblower)*
- **Jurassic Quark** *(Jurassic Park)*
- **Mansfield Pulsar** *(Mansfield Park)*
- **Moby Dichromate** *(Moby Dick)*
- **Of Mice and Mandlebrot** *(Of Mice and Men)*
- **Prime and Probability** *(Pride and Prejudice)*
- **Sense and Special Relativity** *(Sense and Sensibility)*
- **Star Shift Troopers** *(Starship Troopers)*
- **The (0,0,0) of the Species** *(The Origin of the Species)*
- **The Call of the Wild Binomial** *(The Call of the Wild)*
- **The Cydonian Man** *(The Invisible Man)*
- **The Half-Life of the Baskervilles** *(The Hound of the Baskervilles)*
- **The Hunchback of Nova Delta** *(The Hunchback of Notre Dame)*
- **The Man in the Fe<sup>60</sup> Mask** *(The Man in the Iron Mask)*
- **The Original Sin<sup>-1</sup>** *(The Original Sin)*
- **The Old Man and the Selenium** *(The Old Man and the Sea)*
- **The Prince and the Photon** *(The Prince and the Pauper)*
- **The Quark of Monte Christo** *(The Count of Monte Cristo)*
- **The Red Shift of Courage** *(The Red Badge of Courage)*
- **The Wizard of Ozmium** *(The Wizard of Oz)*
- **Through the Looking Spectrometer** *(Through the Looking Glass)*
- **Time-Lord of the Rings** *(Lord of the Rings; Time-Lord is a reference to Doctor Who)*
- **To Kilowatt a Mockingbird** *(To Kill a Mocking Bird)*
- **War of the Parallel Worlds** *(War of the Worlds)*
- **Wuthering Hydrocarbons** *(Wuthering Heights)*

<sup>These are all I came across during my first play-through.</sup>

Comment: I added a crapton more that I've found :)

Comment: And it would appear you alphabetized them. >.>

Comment: Yes, in the name of Science! :) I also just added what books/movies/plays they reference, though I didn't know all of them.  Do you have any clue about the three I missed?